# Starting and stopping music files in Java?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

This is my sound class.

```
public class Sounds extends Thread { 

private String filename;
private Position curPosition;
private final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 524288; 

enum Position { 
    LEFT, RIGHT, NORMAL
};

public Sounds(String wavFile) { 
    filename = wavFile;
    curPosition = Position.NORMAL;
} 

public Sounds(String wavfile, Position p) { 
    filename = wavfile;
    curPosition = p;
} 

public void run() { 

    File soundFile = new File(filename);
    if (!soundFile.exists()) { 
        System.err.println(".wav file not found: " + filename);
        return;
    } 

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
    try { 
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e1) { 
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 

    AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    SourceDataLine auline = null;
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

    try { 
        auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        auline.open(format);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 

    if (auline.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN)) { 
        FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) auline
                .getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
        if (curPosition == Position.RIGHT) 
            pan.setValue(1.0f);
        else if (curPosition == Position.LEFT) 
            pan.setValue(-1.0f);
    } 

    auline.start();
    int nBytesRead = 0;
    byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

    try { 
        while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
            nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } finally { 
        auline.drain();
        auline.close();
    } 
} 
}
```

And this is my ActionListener that I want to stop the music when the user clicks a button. The music plays on start up.

```
btnSound.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnSound.setVisible(false);
        btnNoSound.setVisible(true);
        new Sounds("Sounds/MenuMusic.wav").end();
    }
});
```

I can get the music to play just fine, but I can't figure out how to stop it. I tried using .stop() and .end() but I was told they were deprecated. Anyone have any idea how I can do this? thanks.

Comment: `new Sounds("Sounds/MenuMusic.wav").end();`  Since this is not the **instance** of `Sounds` that is playing, it will achieve nothing.  The code needs to reference the **original `Sounds` object.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the clip class. This is my code for reading a .wav file and playing it:

```
try {
    File file = new File(src); // src is the location of the file
    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(stream);
    clip.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That was, `clip.stop()` will stop the clip. To reset the clip, use `clip.setFramePosition(0)`. Note that `clip` does not *need* to be closed, because if `clip.close()` is called after `clip.start()`, the clip will not play.

Hope that's what you were looking for!

*EDIT*: Scoping

Using scoping in Java, if you declare a local variable in a method, you cannot access it outside of the method. If you want to access the clip outside of the main method, extract it to a field:

```
class Main {
    static Clip clip;
    public static void main (String... args) {
        try {
            File file...
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            ...
        } catch...
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try using that method. But I just can't get it working.

Comment: I have the clip set up and it's working, but I can't access the clip functions outside my main method.

Comment: *"..but I can't access the clip functions outside my main method."*  That's a basic OOP problem and has little to do with the current question.  But my advice is: fix that and use a `Clip` instead.